# React Shufflejs gallery items condensed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I use Shufflejs in a React component, and I use that component in five pages. It's about a gallery with 16 images. It works on the first load, but if I access another page the gallery images are condensed like they are not loaded. If I refresh the page, the items show up.

```
    const element = useRef();
    const [shuffle, setShuffle] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {   
    if (element.current) { 
            setShuffle(new Shuffle(element.current, {
              itemSelector: ".gallery-item",
            }));   } }, []);
```

This is the setup for the component. I use react-router for pages nav, and I don't know why but I expect to get this behavior from it.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue :**

might be due to element might not be available for the first render, and in below code, effect only get called once, after that it will never get called, so if the element is available during the first render your code will execute else not.

```
useEffect(() => {   
    ....
}, []);
```

**Solution :**

So you can change the above code to something like this, in this case whenever the ref `element.current` changes your function get executed

```
useEffect(() => {   
   ....
}, [element.current]);
```

**Final code :**

```
useEffect(() => {   
    if (element.current) { 
        setShuffle(new Shuffle(element.current, {
              itemSelector: ".gallery-item",
        }));   
    } 
}, [element.current]);
```

Comment: Not working, and receive a warning in console.  "React Hook useEffect has an unnecessary dependency: 'element.current'. Either exclude it or remove the dependency array. Mutable values like 'element.current' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component "

Comment: @MocuțaSorin, is that possible to create a demo over stackbliz or codesandbox? so that I can help you more

Comment: Sorry for lately response. I tried but there it works. I have a lot of dependencies in my project. First time they wont load and if i revisit the page they are loaded. If i visit first time and resize the page they are loading imediatelly, or if i trigger a filter action. Weird behaviour. I'm confused.  Shufflejs has a function resetItems. I tried after all DOM is loaded and instaniate the shuffle. Didn't work.  Help me if you have some resources, examples. Thanks for your time